# How does this chunk of code work?

Tags: python

I have trouble understanding how the "iterflattened" method works in this chunk of Python code I run into:

```
import collections
class nested_dict(collections.defaultdict):
    def __init__(self):
        collections.defaultdict.__init__(self, nested_dict)

    def iterflattened(self):
    """
    iterate through values with nested keys flattened into a tuple
    """
        for key, value in self.items():
            if isinstance(value, nested_dict):
                for keykey, value in value.iterflattened():
                    yield (key,) + keykey, value
            else:
                yield (key,), value

nd = nested_dict()
nd["mouse"]["chr1"]["+"] = 311
print(nd)
```

returned:

```
defaultdict(<class '__main__.nested_dict'>, {'mouse': defaultdict(<class '__main__.nested_dict'>, {'chr1': defaultdict(<class '__main__.nested_dict'>, {'+': 311})})})
```

How and when is "iterflattened" called for the first time? Is it called when nd["mouse"] trigers __getitem__? But how? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: No part of this calls `iterflattened`.

Comment: This function is not called from your code. I believe the output which you are getting is because of **collections.defaultdict**. You can read more about it from internet, may be from [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: `nested_dict` is inheriting `defaultdict`s `__repr__` or `__str__` method, which is why `nd` looks like a `defaultdict` when you print it. If you call `print(nd.iterflattened())`, you would get `[(('mouse', 'chr1', '+'), 311)]`

Comment: @user2357112: you are right. I over-thought it. Thank you!

Comment: @RaviShinde: you are right, thank you!

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: You are right with the inheriting. Actually, print(nd.iterflattened()) won't give you the list because it's a generator, but a simple `print([m for m in nd.iterflattened])` will do.